# Запуск postgresql в docker

Tags: postgresql, docker

Слышал на IT-тусовках про запуск postgresql внутри docker-контейнера (в.ч. и проде) с вынесением самой бд из контейнера.

Правильно ли я понял, что речь идет о монтировании (--mount) каталога /var/lib/postgres-$v/data в контейнер? Большие ли накладные расходы от этого? Что мы получаем от этого? Что можно погуглить/почитать на эту тему?

Comment: Речь о вынесении файлов данных постгреса, работающего в контейнере, на наружную файловую систему (будь то отдельный том или ФС хоста). Большие ли расходы? Измерьте на своих нагрузках. Что почитать? Смотря с какой целью.

Answer (score 17):

Для production баз смысла ровно ноль.

Как `postgresql` ДБА выскажу доводы.

- вы должны использовать монтирование директории с хост системы. У докера родная файловая система не годится для интенсивной пишущей нагрузки в принципе никак. И монтирование `datadir` в реальную директория хост системы единственный шанс как-то работать.
- необходимо использовать сеть хост-системы. Это не так критично как файловая система, можете замерить на своём трафике. [Здесь говорят](https://dzone.com/articles/testing-docker-multi-host-network-performance) о 12% разницы. На каких-нибудь полусотне мегабит вероятно можно пренебречь, на гигабите уже можно заметно упереться.

Итак, файловая система необходима хоста, сеть необходима хоста. Итог - а зачем вам вообще база (в смысле получается только её исполняемые бинарники) в докере? Что вы отсюда хотите получить?

Изоляцию процессов? У вас машина с базой целиком должна быть изолирована.

Миграция на другое железо? На другую архитектуру нельзя в принципе перетащить datadir. На другой хост - а в чём разница поставить пакеты нужной major версии базы или разворачивать докер? По-моему, первое сильно проще. А datadir всё равно копировать или штатной репликацией postgresql или чем угодно но только при остановленной СУБД.

Запустить несколько кластеров на одном сервере на разных портах? Докер для этого не нужен. У `debian` и `ubuntu` есть даже отличные скрипты `pg_ctlcluster` позволяющие штатно управлять множеством кластеров postgresql на одной машине, в том числе разных `major` версий. У `redhat`/`centos` такого счастья нет, но держать нужное число кластеров в том числе разных версий опять же не представляет никаких проблем.

При этом пока ни один адепт докера не смог ответить, как выполнять апгрейд кластера `postgresql`. Для `pg_upgrade` необходимы одновременно бинарники и старой и новой версии базы. Вместо одного даунтайма на 5 минут предлагается сначала перезапустить базу в новом контейнере, где будут бинарники старой и новой версии, затем подготовить обновление, обновить, а затем ещё раз перезапускать базу с новым контейнером?

Answer (score 4):

Данные не должны храниться в контейнерах! На эту тему есть хорошая статья в блоге докера - [Containers are not VMs](https://blog.docker.com/2016/03/containers-are-not-vms/). Цитата оттуда:

> I’m sure many of you are saying “yeah, we get that. They’re
>   different”. But even as we say this, we still try and adapt our
>   current thoughts and processes around VMs and apply them to
>   containers.
>
> - “How do I backup a container?”
> - “What’s my patch management strategy for my running containers?”
> - “Where does the application server run?”
>
> To me the light bulb moment came when I realized that Docker is not a
>   virtualization technology, it’s an application delivery technology.
>
> So, how do you backup your container, you don’t. Your data doesn’t
>   live in the container, it lives in a named volume that is shared
>   between 1-N containers that you define.

Answer (score 2):

Пример с docker-compose.yml. Для production лучше не использовать.

```
version: '3.2'
services:
  pg:
    image: postgres:10.0-alpine
    networks:
      - net
    volumes:
      - pg_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_data
    environment:
      PGDATA: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_data
```